# Advanced Counting Puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Suppose we have a house in which every room has an even number of doors. Prove that the number of doors from the house to the outside world is also even.

Comment: Handshaking lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: count the number of sides of doors.

Comment: Good paraphrasing of handshaking lemma :)

Answer (score 3):

It might not be true if we allows doors from a room to itself:

[image: A house with one room: it has one door from outside to inside, and one door within the room]

This is equivalent to having a loop in the graph.  It also can break down with infinite houses.

(*NB*. I can't see this image where I am, so hopefully it shows what I intend it to show.)

Comment: Good example to think about, but it depends on how you define "number of doors". If we define the number of doors as the number of door sides we can see from within the room, then this room has two doors to itself and one door to the outside, which is odd.